# How to download uploaded file in box.com?

Tags: integration

I am doing integration salesforce with box.com so after uploading file i want the download that file.Like in google drive we set approval_prompt=force and response body contain webContentLink for to download that file.How i can get box.com downloadable link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static String downloadBoxFile(String fileId){
    BoxAuthParser bparser;
    bparser=RefreshTokenrequest();
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    string endPointValue = 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/';
    endPointValue=endPointValue+fileId+'/content';
    req.setEndpoint(endPointValue);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+bparser.access_token);
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    system.debug('pANY'+res.getBody());
    return res.getHeader('Location');
}
```

> The above method should help you.The GET request header has a location and that returns the URL for download of the file .

Comment: Above code working fine and finaly my this problem solve.

Comment: Sir i have one more issue that how i can get download link in dropbox for uploaded file .

Comment: When you preview at top you have down arrow for you to download file from drop box.Hope that helps

Comment: I want the link of file in response body so using this link i can download uploaded file on dro.box. I want link of uploaded file in dropbox using rest api.

Answer (score 1):

This is the endpoint to get all files from box.com

https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0/items?limit=5&offset=0

With file Id you can get file download information in json format.

Comment: sir i want the link of single file among more files.

Comment: In JSON you will get download link of each file associated with its other information by which you can download them.  @sandeep

Comment: I am not getting link of file but i  am getting id and name of uploaded file so now i can get url of uploaded file using id or name of file.

Comment: @regal The body will be empty .A location variable in header is needed for download.

Comment: Thanks above link very helpful for me and my problem solved.