# How to download the file in html format from Box api?

Tags: api, integration

[How to download uploaded file in box.com?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45823/how-to-download-uploaded-file-in-box-com/46515#46515)

In the above link the code will give an url (in the response) to download the file. But i want my file from the box to be downloaded in html format. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: what do you mean by html format?

Comment: https://developers.box.com/view/ According to this website, Box will convert documents to html. So i am trying to convert an uploaded ppt to html. But when i am downloading the file i am getting it as ppt only.

Comment: did you check this previous discussion already ? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45823/how-to-download-uploaded-file-in-box-com

Comment: Yes i checked. That is working for me. But it will give me the file in the format in which i have uploaded. But i want my file to get converted to html. How can i do that?